# Haskell - How to split a list into n long subparts with recursion

Tags: haskell

The following code gives a basic idea. I would like to extend it to the rest of the list with recursion, but using where syntax simply gives no capable code. I tried to name the rest of the list with @done, with no success. I'm still learning Haskell through this code so I'd rather not use any easy solutions like splitAt function etc.

```
splitEv :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEv n [] = []
splitEv n (x:xs) = [take n (x:xs)] ++ [(take n(drop n (x:xs)))]
```

Comment: It seems no need to use (:) concat the list:                                                  splitEv n xs = [take n xs] ++ [(take n(drop n xs))]

Comment: Yes, but I want it to work at the end of the list like this splitEv 3 [0..7] == [[0,1,2],[3,4,5], [6,7]]

Comment: `[something] ++ [something]` is a list of length two. Your function returns either an empty list, or a list of length two.

Comment: splitAt is just as easy as take and drop, they do nearly the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last line should be

```
 splitEv n xs = [take n xs] ++ (splitEv n (drop n xs))
```

In the later part of equation splitEv is called for rest of the list, other than first n elements of the list. This will continue until the list is empty.

**Edited** using @chi comment
Few optimizations are possible.
In second line n is not necessary it can be replaced by _. 
In Third line : can be used instead of ++. It's more optimized. Also brackets can be reduced.

```
splitEV  _ [] = []
splitEV n xs = take n xs:(splitEV n $ drop n xs)
```

**Difference between : and ++** (with help of @chepner comment). 
Signature of :

```
  (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

while that of ++ is

```
  (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

: is used to add single element at the head while ++ is used to concatenate two lists. Whenever possible : is used as it is more optimized. Think it as adding an element at the beginning of linked list. You only need to adjust the head element. 
This is only for the metaphor and under the hood more things could be happening.

Comment: I think you need `:` instead of  `++`. Further, I'd remove parentheses for readability, except in `(drop n xs)` where they are needed.

Comment: Thanks it works now. Altough I don't really understand what is the difference between : and ++. I know the first one is able to concat an element to the list and the second one can concat two list.

Comment: @AkosFajszi That... would be the difference. `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` and `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. Further, `(++)` is defined *in terms of* `(:)`, something like `[] ++ ys = ys; (x:xs) ++ ys = x: (xs ++ ys)`.

Comment: Using take and drop like this, isnt it no better then splitAt? Equally trivial.

Comment: As a matter of style, you can remove a level of nesting by writing `take n xs : splitEV n (drop n xs)`. You can also use the worker-wrapper pattern since `n` is constant for every recursive call: `splitEV n = go where go xs = take n xs : go (drop n xs)`. There’s still a bit of redundant work (you traverse each split twice) which could be remedied with `splitAt`, but this method is perfectly readable and fine for what I presume is a homework or self-study assignment.